# read NSData line by line in objective-c

Tags: ios

I am new to iOS.

I have NSData from urlRequest and able to see it in console while using the following code.

```
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

This returns the data as

```
<html>   <head>  </head> <body> myContent..  </body>  </html>
```

How to iterate this data and I need to get them as line by line as NSString, as below

```
     <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
     myContent..
     </body>
     </html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try stringByreplcaingCharater " " with "\n"

Comment: As I am very new to iOS, can you please give any sample urls @MuhammadAdnan?

Comment: NSString *s = @"<html>   <head>  </head> <body> myContent..  </body>  </html>";
    s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@" "];
    s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"\n"];

Comment: One note - with this approach all spaces in `myContent` will be replaced with "\n" too and if you have multiple spaces at a time, you should maybe trim them to get only one

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan, Thanks for your solution. Can you please help the following scenario, which is for my real need, If I have a html response like ..<html><head></head><body>myContent..</body></html>
             .. then how to get this as in every line.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use HTML parse libraries to help you in this task.

You can use libs [GDataXML-HTML](https://github.com/graetzer/GDataXML-HTML), with have good [tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml).

Other good libs for this propose,

[HTMLParser](https://github.com/volodg/HTMLParser)

[Kanna](https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna)

Comment: Thanks man. As I am very new to iOS dev, can you please help me in HTMLParser. How to parse my NSData for that and get formatted html source. I searched lot but couldn't find a way. Hopw you can as a iOS professional. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user4120936, check this link, its a very detailed tutorial, it may help you. https://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

Comment: I looked in that article. It looks only finding URLs and Href like that using XPathQuery right? if any wrong with my understanding req you to pls clear me. I want to get all the html source.